# Twitter API request doesn't works when changing query parameters

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, twitter, native

I'm actually working on a React Native app calling twitter API. I've got a problem when i'm changing query parameters in my Twitter API request, it doesn't work anymore.. here is my code :

```
export async function searchUser(q){
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXX\",oauth_token=\"XXXXX\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1590049055\",oauth_nonce=\"AVheRIfyZ8C\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"mc1W4UKF5BGppOhH1PL2cL8Fxak%3D\"");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "personalization_id=\"v1_pD0Dj0CABSG4A+glp2jC0w==\"; lang=fr; guest_id=v1%3A159004905521391198");

var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: "follow"
};

return fetch("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q="+q, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this,

```
return fetch(`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=${q}`, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```